# how to set binding command on focus in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want something like

when I am trying this it shows an error saying "Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode' to type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode'."

that means focused event doesn't support binding.But how can I achieve that

Comment: Share code please i cannot tell you what is the problem just by looking at this

Comment: Sorry.I missed it    <Entry  Text="{Binding text}"  Focused="{Binding textcommand}">

Comment: Focused cannot be bound to a command.

Answer (score 4):

To invoke a command when an event fires, [`EventToCommandBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior) might be used; example:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Text}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Focused"
                                          Command="{Binding FocusedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

See also [Event to Command Behavior sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/behaviors/eventtocommandbehavior/).